# How much alcohol can I bring into Benin?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, alcohol, duty-free, benin

My GF goes on a medical mission (from a EU country) to Benin shortly, and wants to take some wine for her hosts. How much can she import duty-free?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the IATA TravelCentre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/bj-Benin-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm):

> Import regulations:

> Free import by tourists over 15 years of age:
>
> - 200 cigarettes or 100 cigarillos or 25 cigars or 250 grams of tobacco;
> - **1 bottle of wine and 1 bottle of spirits;**
> - 1/2 liter of eau de toilette and 1/4 liter of perfume.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that they talk about "one bottle", but it doesn't mention size. Does that mean that you can take a 3 liter bottle? Asking for a friend :-)

Comment: @vasin1987 I am probably completely misreading your comment, but Benin has been independent from france for like half a century, hasn't it?

Comment: Oopss. I see french in tag of benin so I thought it is france. Sorry.